# T-SQL round special cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I need a way to round in T-SQL (SQL Server 2005).

```
0.0041 -> 0.005
0.0049 -> 0.005
0.0040 -> 0.004
```

I have tried the following select with `ROUND()`:

```
SELECT ROUND(0.004, 3,1) + .001
```

The problem is: it doesn't work with 0.0040 -> 0.004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT CEILING(1000 * 0.0041) / 1000.0
```

produces:

```
0.005
```

whereas this:

```
SELECT CEILING(1000 * 0.004) / 1000.0
```

produces:

```
0.004
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT X 
, CEILING(X * 1000) / 1000 AS X4
FROM (
SELECT 0.0041 X UNION ALL 
SELECT 0.0049 UNION ALL 
SELECT 0.0040 ) A
```

Output:

```
X                                       X4
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
0.0041                                  0.005000
0.0049                                  0.005000
0.0040                                  0.004000
```